# How to stop music started via SndPlaySound

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, playback

At this [Website](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/embed_resources_2.htm) I  found how to add music into a .res file and then use it in your delphi .exe. Here is the code for starting the WAVE song.

```
procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
   hFind, hRes: THandle;
   Song: PChar;
 begin
  hFind := FindResource(HInstance, 'SonicSong', 'WAVE') ;
  if hFind <> 0 then begin
    hRes:=LoadResource(HInstance, hFind) ;
    if hRes <> 0 then begin
      Song:=LockResource(hRes) ;
      if Assigned(Song) then SndPlaySound(Song, snd_ASync or snd_Memory) ;
      UnlockResource(hRes) ;
    end;
    FreeResource(hFind) ;
  end;
end;
```

So what I would like to know is how do I stop the music when I want to without closing the application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the [`sndPlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798676(v=vs.85).aspx) function with the first parameter set to `nil`, which causes the currently playing sound to stop. As the second parameter use the `SND_ASYNC` flag, because as the reference says, you must use this flag to terminate an asynchronously played waveform sound, which you are playing in your code:

```
sndPlaySound(nil, SND_ASYNC);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code by using the `SND_RESOURCE` feature of `PlaySound()` instead of `sndPlaySound()`:

```
procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PlaySound('SonicSong', HInstance, SND_AYNC or SND_RESOURCE);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PlaySound(nil, HInstance, SND_AYNC or SND_RESOURCE);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

test with:

```
PlaySound(nil, 0, 0);
```